# JavaScript 5 digits all unique upto 1000. Help me improove this code to generate all random numbers unique

Tags: javascript

```
var row = 10000, column = 10;

var studentReceipts = new Array();

for(c= 0; c<row; ++c){

    studentReceipts[c] = new Array();

    for(c2=0; c2<column; c2++){
        var randomNumber= Math.ceil(Math.floor( Math.random() * 89999+10000 ));
        //incase a value already exists, skip
        if(studentReceipts.indexOf(randomNumber) > -1) continue;
        studentReceipts[c][c2] = randomNumber;
        document.write(" " + studentReceipts[c][c2]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please see [How to ask a question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myArr = [];

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
    if (myArr.indexOf(num)==-1){
        myArr.push(num);
    } else{
      i--;
    }
}
console.log(myArr);
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, and for the solution am so grateful

Comment: Yeah did so thou, due to low reputation my vote was not reflected nevertheless , thanks

Comment: No issues dear! ;)